# Conditional CDF from joint CDF using partial derivatives

Tags: conditional-probability, partial-derivative

Is there a way of finding the conditional CDF $F(x\mid y)$ by using the partial derivative $\dfrac{dF(x,y)}{dy}$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$F(x|y)=\int_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{f(z,y)}{f(y)}dz=\dfrac{\dfrac{dF(x,y)}{dy}}{f(y)}$$

Since $$ \dfrac{dF(x,y)}{dy}=\dfrac{d}{dy}\int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f(z,w) dz dw=\int_{-\infty}^x f(z,y) dz$$

Comment: Can this be generalized to non absolutely continuous distributions?

Comment: @MarkusPeschl I'm not sure but I will suspect that the answer is no since with a singular random variable the partial derivative might always be zero.